# Generic type wrapping in TypeScript for tuples

Tags: typescript, generics, types, tuples

I need to add a type declaration to a function which maps elements of a tuple `[Foo<A>, Foo<B>, ...]` to a function `() => [A, B, ...]`. How can I achieve this in TypeScript?

This example is structurally similar to the relevant part of the application:

```
interface SomethingWithAValue<T> { value: T; }

function collect(array) {
  return () => array.map(a => a.value);
}
```

This returns a tuple of the values associated with each object. What would the type declaration for `collect` look like?

Pseudocode:

```
function collect<[SomethingWithAValue<T>...](array: [SomethingWithAValue<T>...]): () => [T...];
```

---

Update in response to jonrsharpe's suggestion:

```
interface SomethingWithAValue<T> { value: T; }

function collect<T>(array: SomethingWithAValue<T>[]): () => T[] {
  return () => array.map(a => a.value);
}

type myTupleType = [string, number];

let somethings: [SomethingWithAValue<string>, SomethingWithAValue<number>];
somethings = [{ value: 'foo' }, { value: 5 }];

let fn: () => myTupleType = collect(somethings);
```

This does not work:

```
Argument of type '[SomethingWithAValue<string>, SomethingWithAValue<number>]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SomethingWithAValue<string>[]'.
  Types of property 'pop' are incompatible.
    Type '() => SomethingWithAValue<string> | SomethingWithAValue<number>' is not assignable to type '() => SomethingWithAValue<string>'.
      Type 'SomethingWithAValue<string> | SomethingWithAValue<number>' is not assignable to type 'SomethingWithAValue<string>'.
        Type 'SomethingWithAValue<number>' is not assignable to type 'SomethingWithAValue<string>'.
          Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Comment: That would be `collect(array: SomethingWithAValue[]): () => string[]`, but you should have `array.map(a => a.value)`

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry, my bad, I added the generic type to `SomethingWithAValue`. You are right, if all values are strings, this is trivial. Thanks for the hint regarding `array.value`, fixed.

Comment: In that case `collect<T>(array: SomethingWithAValue<T>[]): () => T[]`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you, but I don't think that works for tuples, see my update.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

UPDATE: The answer below is obsolete as of TS3.1.  I believe you can now use [mapped tuple types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26063) and [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) to get the behavior you want:

```
type ExtractValue<T extends ReadonlyArray<SomethingWithAValue<any>>> =
  { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends SomethingWithAValue<infer V> ? V : never };

function collect<T extends ReadonlyArray<SomethingWithAValue<any>>>(
  array: T
): () => ExtractValue<T> {
  return () => array.map(a => a.value) as any;
}
```

And let's use it... First let's make it easy to get a tuple type with a helper function `tuple()` which takes in a variadic number of arguments and outputs a tuple (this was made possible as of TS3.0)

```
type Narrowable = string | number | boolean | undefined | null | void | {};
const tuple = <T extends Narrowable[]>(...t: T) => t;
```

And let's see if it works:

```
const result = collect(tuple({ value: 10 }, { value: "hey" }, { value: true }));
// const result: () => [number, string, boolean]
```

Looks good!

---

OLD ANSWER:

There are no [variadic kinds](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453) in TypeScript, so there's no way to type a generic tuple (nothing like the syntax `[T...]` exists).

As a workaround, you can provide function overloads for tuples of any length up to some reasonable maximum:

```
function collect<A, B, C, D, E>(array: [SomethingWithAValue<A>, SomethingWithAValue<B>, SomethingWithAValue<C>, SomethingWithAValue<D>, SomethingWithAValue<E>]): () => [A, B, C, D, E];
function collect<A, B, C, D>(array: [SomethingWithAValue<A>, SomethingWithAValue<B>, SomethingWithAValue<C>, SomethingWithAValue<D>]): () => [A, B, C, D];
function collect<A, B, C>(array: [SomethingWithAValue<A>, SomethingWithAValue<B>, SomethingWithAValue<C>]): () => [A, B, C];
function collect<A, B>(array: [SomethingWithAValue<A>, SomethingWithAValue<B>]): () => [A, B];
function collect<A>(array: [SomethingWithAValue<A>]): () => [A];
function collect<T>(array: SomethingWithAValue<T>[]): () => T[] {
  // implementation
}
```

That should work for tuples up to length 5, and you can add other overloads at the top to get up to whatever you need in practice.  It's verbose and ugly but it should work.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Are you sure your fallback is going to work ? Since you need to pass a SomethingWithAValue<T>[], you can only use a single T for all values in the array. Don't you think SomethingWithAValue<any>[] would work better as the default ?

Comment: It will infer a union type for `T`, so you'd get at least get something with a union of the element types, which is somewhat better than `any`.

Comment: Actually, the fallback won't work, but not because of `T`... it's because it will use the first overload.  Hmm, must refactor...

Comment: Unfortunately it won't, I just tried, and this `collect([new SomethingWithAValue<number>(), new SomethingWithAValue<string>()]);` will generate an error (only left the fallback without the other overloads)

Comment: Okay, you're right, the fallback isn't helping; I'll remove it.

Comment: Variadic functions should only be allowed for homogeneous argument lists anyway.

Comment: Best you can do in that case is to manually specify the value of `T` in the call, like `collect<string|number|boolean>(...)`, which will work even without the fallback.

Comment: Someone just upvoted this very old answer so I updated it to reflect the current way of doing this

Comment: With variadic types being introduced in TS 4.0, I wonder if it could be simplified? So far I couldn't come up with a technique to unpack a tuple with more complex type

Comment: @jcalz: About this `as any`: is there any `ReadonlyArray.map` implementation that returns the right types (a tuple of types instead of an array of types)?