# Convert the type signature of an array of items to an array of those items within a wrapper - Array<Wrapper<T>>

Tags: typescript

I need to turn a generic array to an array of those items but in a wrapper:

```
declare type MyGenericArray = [number, string, boolean]
declare type WrappedGeneraicArray = Wrap<MyGenericArray>

// WrappedGeneraicArray = [Wrapped<number>, Wrapped<string>, Wrapped<boolean>]

type Wrap = ??
```

I am trying to use `keyof` but I think that just works for objects and not arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic mapped type that extends Array should do it:

```
// example
type Wrapped<T> = { wrapped: T };

type Wrap<T extends Array<unknown>> = {
    [K in keyof T]: Wrapped<T[K]>
}
type MyGenericArray = [number, string, boolean];
type WrappedGenericArray = Wrap<MyGenericArray>;
```

Comment: What about function return types?

`function wrap<T extends any[]>(arr: T): Wrap<T> { return arr.map(val => ({ wrapped: val })) as Wrap<T> }`

`const result = wrap([1, 'a', null])` results in type `Wrapped<string | number | null>[]`

Is it possible to get `[ Wrapped<string>, Wrapped<number>, Wrapped<null> ]` instead?

Comment: A pretty good solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46013198/388994 . It needs one more utility function `const tuple = <T extends any[]>(...t: T) => t` and then `wrap(tuple(1, 'a', null))` yields the correct type. It would be best to do away with the `tuple` wrapper, but it solves the problem.