# Infer tuple types from an array of classes with generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a function `someFunction`

```
function someFunction<T extends SomeClass<any>[]>(
  name: string,
  callback: (dependencyValues: any[]) => void,
  dependencies: T,
```

I want `dependencyValues` to be a tuple inferred by the values in `dependencies`.

For example:

```
someFunction(
    'someName', // name
    (dependencyValues: [number, boolean, string]) => { // callback
        ...
        ... do something
        ...
    }, 
    [new SomeClass<number>(), new SomeClass<boolean>(), new SomeClass<string>()] // dependencies
)
```

What do I need to change in my function definition in order achieve that?

Thanks !

I tried use that: [Generic type wrapping in TypeScript for tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46012987/generic-type-wrapping-in-typescript-for-tuples) but couldn’t figure out how I can use that in my problem

Answer (score 0):

Using [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types), we can infer `T` as a tuple, which means we can then "loop over" the tuple in the type of `callback` and infer the type parameter inside.

```
function someFunction<T extends SomeClass<any>[]>(
  name: string,
  callback: (dependencyValues: { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends SomeClass<infer U> ? U : never }) => void,
  dependencies: [...T],
) {}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N7onPN)